# NodeJS with Redis message queue - How to set multiple consumers (threads)

Tags: node.js, multithreading, redis, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I have a nodejs project that is exposing a simple rest api for an external web application. This webhook must cope with a large number of requests per second as well as return 200 OK very quickly to the caller. In order for that to happen I investigate a redis simple queue to be enqueued with each request's to be handled asynchronously later on (via a consumer thread).

The redis simple queue seems like an easy way to achieve this task (https://github.com/smrchy/rsmq)

1) Is rsmq.receiveMessage() { .......  } a blocking method? if this handler is slow - will it impact my server's performance?

2) If the answer to question 1 is true - Is it recommended to extract the consumption of the messages to an external micro service? (a dedicated consumer)? what are the best practices to create multi threaded consumers on such environment?

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422094/multple-node-js-message-recievers-for-a-redis-queue

Answer (score 0):

You can use pubsub feature provided by redis https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

You can publish to various channels without any knowledge of subscribers . Subscribers can subscribe to the channels they wish.

sreeni

Comment: Yes, But I was asking regarding the capability of nodejs as a consumer (is it a good practice to create multiple listeners with node? or should i extract my consumers outside the project?)

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it won't block the event loop, however you will only start processing a second message once you call the "next" method, i.e., you will process one message at a time. To overcome this, you can start multiple workers in parallel. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984677/7201847

2) That's an architectural decision that depends on the load you have to support and the hardware capacity you have. I would recommend at least two Node.js processes, one for adding the messages to the queue and another one to  actually processing them, with the option to start additional worker processes if needed, depending on the results of your performance tests.